# Respository connector plugin in jenkins not pulling artifacts from nexus

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, nexus

I am trying to retrieve the maven artifact from nexus using the resository connector plugin in Jenkins.

Iam using Jenkins version 2.60.1 and nexus 3.2.0

The War file is pulled from nexus but it is 0 bytes,Can you let me know if there anything wrong in my configurations.

I have done the below configurations:

in the Artifact resolver configurations:

1.) Fail on error,Enable repository logging are checked
2.) Release update policy and snapshot update policy are never
3.) Artifacts with maven coordinates defined and Extension is war.

in the system configurations :

Artifact Resolver
Checked Repo manager and specified the url for nexus.

Jenkins Console log:

```
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace /home/jenkins/workspace/CORE-DEPLOY-DEV
INFO: define repo: [Repository id=central, type=default, url=https://company.nexus.com/repository/maven-public/, isRepositoryManager=true]
Resolving artifact com.company.esb.NexusTest.source.out:NexusTest:pom:0.0.1
Resolved artifact com.company.esb.NexusTest.source.out:NexusTest:pom:0.0.1 from central (https://company.nexus.com/repository/maven-public/, releases+snapshots, managed)
Invalid artifact descriptor for com.company.esb.NexusTest.source.out:NexusTest:war:0.0.1: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model
[FATAL] Non-readable POM /tmp/repositoryconnector-repo/com/company/esb/NexusTest/source/out/NexusTest/0.0.1/NexusTest-0.0.1.pom: input contained no data @ 

Resolving artifact com.company.esb.NexusTest.source.out:NexusTest:war:0.0.1
Resolved artifact com.company.esb.NexusTest.source.out:NexusTest:war:0.0.1 from central (https://company.nexus.com/repository/maven-public/, releases+snapshots, managed)
deleted file:/home/jenkins/workspace/CORE-DEPLOY-DEV/NexusTest-0.0.1.war
copy /tmp/repositoryconnector-repo/com/company/esb/NexusTest/source/out/NexusTest/0.0.1/NexusTest-0.0.1.war to file:/home/jenkins/workspace/CORE-DEPLOY-DEV/NexusTest-0.0.1.war
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: First have you manually downloaded the files? Furthermore I would check this: `[FATAL] Non-readable POM /tmp/repositoryconnector-repo/com/company/esb/NexusTest/source/out/NexusTest/0.0.1/NexusTest-0.0.1.pom: input contained no data @ `....

Comment: yes through browser i have downloaded from nexus.In jenkins iam expecting repository connector plugin to download the artifact.I am not sure why iam getting fatal error.

Comment: proxy/authentication/credentials in Jenkins missing ?